# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_n^{n+1}\cos^2(u^2) \, du$

Tags: real-analysis

Question is how to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_n^{n+1}\cos^2(u^2) \, du$ without using the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

I have looked at [Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_n^{n+1} {\sin x \over x} dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589377/find-lim-n-to-infty-int-nn1-sin-x-over-x-dx) which looks similar, but the solutions on there do not work so nicely for this problem.

I tried to see if I could recreate the sandwich solution for the equation here:

$$0\le \cos^2(x^2)\le1$$
$$\int_n^{n+1}\cos^2(u^2)\,du \le \int_n^{n+1}1\,du=n+1-n=1$$
$$\int_n^{n+1}\cos^2(u^2)\,du \ge \int_n^{n+1}0\,du=0$$
but it doesn't work out for me. I am not sure if it is even possible to use a sandwich method here. If so then I would need to use different values because here I end up with $1$ and $0$, but I am pretty sure the final answer is supposed to be $1/2$. Anyone have a hint or idea as to what theorem or direction I need?

Answer (score 6):

We have $$\cos^2(u^2)=\frac12(1+\cos(2u^2)),$$ so 
$$\int^{n+1}_n\cos^2(u^2)\,du=\frac12\int^{n+1}_n 1\,du+\frac12\int^{n+1}_n \cos(2u^2)\,du=\frac12+\frac12\int^{n+1}_n \cos(2u^2)\,du.$$
But $\int^\infty_0 \cos(2u^2)\,du$ is convergent (cf. [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)), so $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int^{n+1}_n\cos(2u^2)\,du=0,$$ and your limit is $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=v^{1/2}$ to get the integral

$$\int_{n^2}^{(n+1)^2} \frac{\cos^2 v}{2v^{1/2}}\,dv.$$

Now use $\cos^2 v = (1+\cos 2v)/2$ to get

$$\tag 1 \frac{1}{4}\left (\int_{n^2}^{(n+1)^2}\frac{dv}{v^{1/2}} + \int_{n^2}^{(n+1)^2}\frac{\cos 2v}{v^{1/2}}\, dv \right ).$$

The first integral in $(1)$ equals $2.$ In the second integral, integrate by parts to see its limit is $0$ as $n\to \infty.$ Thus the desired limit is $\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot 2 = \dfrac{1}{2}.$